Homeowners insurance requiring auto Insurance
Is this a normal requirement to face while obtaining quotes for a home owners insurance policy? If I'm understanding this insurance agent correctly all three quotes they provided for insurance of a home we're looking to purchase require the purchase of auto insurance through them. Does this make sense, is this a common practice? Is this an agent just trying to secure more sales for themselves?
Could it be that the presence of an automobile changes the risk profile at the home? What could be the connection exactly? (Also what if the homeowner doesn't even own a car? How would this requirement make sense in such a scenario?)

Are you sure they are requiring an auto-insurance policy from THEM, and not just having  an auto-insurance policy with certain coverage levels?

I added a united-states tag to your question since it seems that is where you are (and norms and laws differ around the world). If I've got that wrong please edit or comment.

It is common for insurers to offer a discount if they are handling both the home and auto policies. So that might be required in order to get a specific price. It will almost certainly be required if you want them to issue an umbrella policy on top of those.
But I can't see any reason an insurance company would completely refuse to insure someone's house unless they got to carry the car policy as well, or vice versa. Among other things, not everyone has both.
I'd suggest asking another agent for quotes...

It may also be illegal, worth checking with insurance regulators.

"It will almost certainly be required if you want them to issue an umbrella policy on top of those" -- does that mean someone who doesn't have a car can't get an umbrella policy?

@nanoman: Not having an auto policy at all shouldn't be a problem for an umbrella. Having one with another insurer could be messy, and I suspect they won't want to deal with it. Having insurers argue about exactly who is responsible for what is generally ugly.

Thanks -- my confusion is that you cite "not everyone has both" (house and car) in the second paragraph, but it should also apply to the first paragraph (umbrella).

@nanoman The first paragraph says "if" they are handling both policies, and they certainly can't handle it if it doesn't exist.  You obviously wouldn't want to put a non-existent policy under an umbrella, nor could you, so I don't understand how it could be confusing.

Not worth quibbling about, I think. Move to table the amendment.

@littleadv I thought that too. Some people don't drive due to disability or other valid reasons. I can't imagine it would be lawful to require a non-driver to purchase auto insurance.

From my personal experience, at least here in California, yes. For whatever reason, some insurers are only issuing new homeowners policies in CA if you bundle it with auto insurance. Others aren't issuing new policies at all.
Why? Who knows. Assuming a car is parked at the insured address, the weather-related incidents that damaged homes in the last few years (which are largely cited as the reason insurance companies are reducing homeowners issuances in CA) would probably have damaged the car as well (unless you evacuated). I'm not seeing a reduction in risk there, but I'm not an insurance underwriter.

"only issuing new homeowners policies in CA if you bundle it with auto insurance" -- does this mean there isn't an exception for people who don't have a car at all?

@nanoman that's right. I have a car and a great auto policy so I'm not switching - it made me ineligible for those policies that required bundling.

The major disaster risk for CA homeowner's are wildfires. When there's a fire, people use their cars to evacuate, so disaster risk does affect cars less. Otherwise, what's the weather risk in CA? No hurricanes, tornadoes, or people crashing in snow. The other thing is cars always depreciate. CA's constant building code upgrades (fire sprinklers, sealed envelope with heat recovery ventilators, EV wiring in the garage) combined with older housing stock, often from the 50's-60's, makes replacement value significantly higher than market value.

The other natural disaster risk in CA is earthquakes. Particularly for cars parked in a garage, the insurance could get messy if the garage collapses on top of the car and both are covered by different parties.

@user71659 - although it does seem that news pictures of burned out homes after a wildfire always seem to have a burned car nearby. Perhaps that is a 'requirement' to be newsworthy.

@Ryan Earthquakes don't affect homeowner's insurance because they are like floods: it isn't covered by standard policies. Insurers must offer a supplemental policy, but less than 15% of individuals buy them. Of that share 2/3 are ceded to the State's program, the California Earthquake Authority. Also, large portions of CA are not subject to significant earthquake risk, specifically the Central Valley.

For AAA the California angle seems to apply as you mention in the answer. This is what I was told: "AAA is one of the very few companies left selling home insurance in the state of CA right now with decent prices. So the company is requiring the auto insurance to help offset the risk of selling too much homeowners insurance.". For Farmers they will sell a HOI policy without requiring auto but give a bundle discount. Geico seems to be out of the CA market. Homesite will insure and Bamboo too from what I gathered, both without requiring auto insurance.

It sounds like the agent is saying "to get this price, you need to also have auto through this carrier" which is very common -- you get a multi-policy discount when you have more than one policy at the same insurer. So, the agent (and, perhaps, the companies) are giving you what looks like their best possible price, because they expect to also get the auto business from you. (Similarly, you'll probably also get an auto discount for having homeowners with the same company.)
So, you might want to get quotes for the whole package if you want to have the lowest cost option.
Separately, homeowners insurance frequently comes with some form of bundled liability insurance, and that in turn may require that you have auto liability insurance such that they won't have to take on liability if you cause a traffic accident. I don't know how common this secondary reason is, but I've certainly seen it in specific liability policies in the past. (In fact, those policies typically require that you have the maximum offered level of auto liability insurance, before the separate liability coverage kicks in.)

Yes, an umbrella liability policy would require all policies to be with the one carrier and each policy have a specified liability coverage.
